# How can I convert PointCloud2 to PointCloud?

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !  I have some problems when I run a "laser-perception.launch" of PR2. The errors are:

```
Client [/point_cloud_assembler] wants topic /tilt_scan_cloud_filtered to have datatype/md5sum [**sensor_msgs/PointCloud**/d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca], but our version has [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181]. Dropping connection
```

and  so is the topic `/tilt_scan_cloud`. The topics' type is `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`.

So I think the solution is that `PointCloud2` should be converted to `PointCloud`. But I don't know **how convert PointCloud2 to PointCloud in a launch file.**  thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140881/how-can-i-convert-pointcloud2-to-pointcloud?/) by [hannuaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/13401/hannuaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hannuaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/13401/hannuaa/) on 2014-03-17**:
My ROS is fuerte. the "laser-perception.launch" is in http://wiki.ros.org/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Making%20collision%20maps%20from%20self-filtered%20tilting%20laser%20data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

via @neil-traft:

Your question is covered in the [PCL Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview#Converting_between_the_.60sensor_msgs::PointCloud.60_and_.60sensor_msgs::PointCloud2.60_format). In particular, you can either run the [point_cloud_converter](http://wiki.ros.org/point_cloud_converter) node, or you can use [sensor_msgs::convertPointCloud2ToPointCloud](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs.html#a56242d12e091c19f7e829bc6b0b0b709).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2